# New Tab is not opening in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, tabs

New Tab is not opening in Selenium

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class SimpleTest {
  @Test
  public void TestMethod() throws InterruptedException
  {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\22November2017\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
   } 
}
```

Please help me find the error

Answer (score 0):

> open the link in new Tab.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("http://www.google.com/")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

Comment: Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);  --> Its working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: But Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t") --> Its not working . My code as like this driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t")); Empty Tab is not opening

Comment: OK. But I want to learn opening new empty tab also. Do you have any other code for that?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
OR
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t"); 
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code..it opens Gmail into new tab and switch to it.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class SimpleTest {
      @Test
      public void TestMethod() throws InterruptedException{
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\22November2017\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 
                driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());                              
                driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a *New Tab* with the `linkText("Gmail")` you can use the following code block :

```
String URL="http://www.google.com";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
Actions newTab = new Actions(driver); 
newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptExecutor to do it

```
Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor)driver;
js.executescript("var win = window.open('"+ YourURLHere + "', '_blank');win.focus(); ");
```

Above code will open new tab and navigate to the URL provided and focus on the new tab.